# Spring boot actuator endpoints not exposed via HTTP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

we are some problems with a Spring Boot 1.5.2 application and the actuator endpoints.

Sometimes when we start the spring boot application, spring mvc don't expose the actuators endpoints via HTTP. I don't find any pattern, I neww start the same application 3 or 4 times in order to expose these endpoints.

In this application we are using:

- Java 8
- Spring boot 1.5.2
- Spring 4.3.7

The actuator are configure adding the next dependencie to build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

The configuration in application.yml:

```
management:
    context-path: /private/actuator
    security:
        enabled: false
```

In LOG we expect to find some like this:

```
2018-12-05 15:15:54.585 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/billing],methods=[GET]}" onto public wtn.integration.webmodel.billing.response.BillingResponse 
wtn.integration.controller.BillingController.process() 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.587 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events/recover/{reportId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventCon
troller.recover(java.lang.Long) 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.587 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events/recover/{reportId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventCo
ntroller.recover(java.lang.Long,wtn.integration.api.event.bean.Event) 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.588 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events/discard/{reportId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventCon
troller.discard(java.lang.Long) 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.588 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events],methods=[POST]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventController.process(wt
n.integration.api.event.request.EventRequest) 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.591 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframew
ork.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.591 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.
Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) 
2018-12-05 15:15:54.672 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationCon
text@1b7f1011: startup date [Wed Dec 05 15:15:46 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.978 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || appli
cation/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String) 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.979 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/env || /private/actuator/env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.979 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/beans || /private/actuator/beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.979 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/configprops || /private/actuator/configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.981 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/info || /private/actuator/info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.982 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/heapdump || /private/actuator/heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.983 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String) 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.983 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.983 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/loggers || /private/actuator/loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.984 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/health || /private/actuator/health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal) 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.984 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/mappings || /private/actuator/mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.985 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/dump || /private/actuator/dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.985 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String) 
2018-12-05 15:15:55.986 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/actuator/metrics || /private/actuator/metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
```

But we found:

```
2018-12-05 15:27:10.713 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/billing],methods=[GET]}" onto public wtn.integration.webmodel.billing.response.BillingResponse 
wtn.integration.controller.BillingController.process() 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.715 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events/discard/{reportId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventController.discard(java.lang.Long) 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.715 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events/recover/{reportId}],methods=[POST]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventController.recover(java.lang.Long,wtn.integration.api.event.bean.Event) 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.715 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events/recover/{reportId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventController.recover(java.lang.Long) 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.715 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/private/events],methods=[POST]}" onto public void wtn.integration.controller.EventController.process(wtn.integration.api.event.request.EventRequest) 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.718 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.718 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) 
2018-12-05 15:27:10.817 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6aedc770: startup date [Wed Dec 05 15:27:04 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy 
2018-12-05 15:27:12.156 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup 
2018-12-05 15:27:12.158 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'getDataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure 
2018-12-05 15:27:12.165 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'connectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting its exposure:

```
management:
  server:
    servlet:
      context-path: /manage
   endpoints:
      web:
        exposure:
            include: '*'
```

Comment: Hi @ricktg, thank you. I try tomorrow but this don't explain me why my config works sometimes and sometimes not and why is working always in another projects with same configuration. Thanks.

Comment: I read in Spring boot 1.5.2 documentation: "By default, all endpoints except for shutdown are enabled." (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html). @ricktg may be the config you propose is for spring boot 2???